# Casting Pytorch's tensor elements the type "float" instead of "double"

Tags: arrays, casting, pytorch, tensor, autoencoder

I had a matrix saved as a numpy type, call it "X_before" (for example, its shape is 100*30).

Since I want to feed it to an AutoEncoder using Pytorch library, I converted it to `torch.tensor` like this:

```
X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_before, dtype=torch)
```

Then, I got the following error:

> ```
> expected scalar type Float but found Double
> ```

Next, I tried to make elements as "float" and then convert them torch.tensor:

```
X_before = X_before.astype(float)
X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_before)
```

Again, the same error happens.
How should I solve this issue? How can I convert the type of elements in a torch.tensor object to another type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
X_tensor = torch.tensor(X_before, dtype=torch.float32)
```

You can see the list of types here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

You can change the type:

```
X_tensor=X_tensor.type(torch.float64)
```

(Note that float64 is double, while float32 is the standardd float)

Answer (score 1):

The other simple way to do it is:

```
X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X_before).type(torch.float)
```